# Call Function in Different Class in Swift(fatal error)?

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I have a class which is for bluetooth data receiving and I wonder to send the receiving data to class UIViewController and do the realtime plotting(CorePlot)

```
class BluetoothManager: NSObject {
   func dataReceiving(value: [Int]){
      for (var m=0 ; m<5 ; m++){
         dataOne[m] = value[2*m]
         dataTwo[m] = value[2*m+1] 
      }
   MainController().plot(dataOne: [Int], dataTwo: [Int])
}
```

MainController class:

```
class MainController: UIViewController,CPTScatterPlotDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var graphView: CPTGraphHostingView!

    private var scatterGraph : CPTXYGraph? = nil
    typealias plotDataType = [CPTScatterPlotField : Double]
    private var dataForPlot = [plotDataType]()

    func plot(dataOne: [Int], dataTwo: [Int]){
        let newGraph = CPTXYGraph(frame: CGRectZero)
        graphView.hostedGraph = newGraph
        ...
    }
}
```

When the procedure goes to `graphView.hostedGraph = newGraph` , there will have a fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have tried call the plot function in the MainController class, it was worked!

Can anybody help me to fix this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you correctly connect the `graphView` outlet in the IB?

Comment: You're using weak reference for your outlet, this may be a problem also. Recommended by Apple since iOS6 is to strong them, may be worth trying.

Comment: @Mahakala I tried! but it seems not work...but still thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the `MainController` in the line

```
MainController().plot(dataOne: [Int], dataTwo: [Int])
```

Therefore the `@IBOutlet weak var graphView: CPTGraphHostingView!` is `nil` - therefore your code crashes.

You **must not** create a new instance of the `MainController` the way you currently do - either instantiate it via the storyboard, or pass in the correct nib file. For both cases you have to set the MainController as controller class in the IB and connect the outlet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't know how to do it exactly... Because I'm new to Xcode and Swift in iOS delopment. Could you tell me how to do it? I'll be very grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have declared plot as an instance method, and you are calling it as a class method.

You need to change this line:

```
func plot(dataOne: [Int], dataTwo: [Int]){
```

To this line:

```
class func plot(dataOne: [Int], dataTwo: [Int]){
```

If you need to call it like you do it

Answer (score 0):

`MainController()` creates a new instance of the `MainController` class which is different from the object in Interface Builder.

You need the reference to the `MainController` object in Interface Builder

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't know how to do it exactly... Because I'm new to Xcode and Swift in iOS delopment. Could you tell me how to do it? I'll be very grateful. Thank you!